# How do I send a raw POST request in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, http, http-post

How would I send a raw POST request in Visual Basic .NET (2010)? When I say raw, I mean without using System.Net.WebRequest to form one, but rather by forming your own headers and sending them with the StreamWriter..

I think I know how to do it with a GET request, but I'm not sure how I would send a POST request.

...

Example GET request (NOTE THAT HERE I USE WEBREQUEST, WHICH I DON'T WANT TO):

```
Private Function HTTPGet(ByVal URL As String) As String
    On Error GoTo fail
    Dim Output As String = String.Empty

    Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Request.Method = "GET"

    Using Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse
        Using Stream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream
            Output = (New StreamReader(Stream)).ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Using

    Return Output
        fail:
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked up the relevant specification to see what the wire format of an HTTP POST is?  This place isn't a roaming code factory, after all.  You need to show you're involved in this process too.  There's also several questions unanswered before you get to *how* you'd do this, such as: why do you need to do this using raw sockets and self-rolled code instead of the perfectly adequate HttpWebRequest library?  What kind of data do you need to send with this POST?  Is it simple key/value pairs, XML, json, mime-multipart?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to manually create these POST's, you will have to do a little research on HTTP requests and sockets. Sockets will create connections to a destination service and let you determine what data you want to send. To build the data properly, you will need to research what the format will need to be for an HTTP POST.

Check out this link to learn more about HTTP GET/POST. Scroll down to (The POST Method) to see a sample HTTP POST.

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

Here is a link on sockets:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx